# Google Oauth 2.0 code - getting Fixed Oauth credentials

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to google cloud SQL API from GAS script.

The difficulty I have is I got the Oauth Code from API Console for my GAS script, which works only once and not on a daily basis.The second time I run the script using the same Oauth Code it gives an error msg: **"Returned Code 401"**

**Sample script:**

```
 var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta3/projects/XXXXXXX/instances/XXXXXXXX/operations/XXXXXXXXXXX";
  var headers = {"Accept":"application/json", 
                 "Content-Type":"application/json", 
                 "Authorization":"Bearer XXXXXXXXX"
                   };
  var options = {"method":"GET",
                 "headers": headers,
                };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
```

The screenshot gives the location from where I get my unique key fr Oauth.

https://drive.google.com/a/ssomens.com/?tab=mo#folders/0B_f0d7mdbV_UYWh4cDBEdndSZE0

Where to get the correct Oauth keys, such that I no need to keep giving new tokens daily, I need a FIXED Token such that my script will run daily w/o any issues. I have checked lots of SITES nd documentation, bt no use.

Plz any help will  be welcome, I m stuck in this fr the past 1 week.

Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2 is a little more complicated than just a token that you can put in your header every time.  There is a multi-step flow where you send the user to Google's service to get back a token that you can then send in the API calls, this then allows you to make calls on behalf of that user.  Making this kind of OAuth call from GAS is documented at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#making_requests_to_services_with_oauth.

An alternative is 'service accounts' where you create a service account that has access to your Cloud SQL instance, save some credentials inside your app, and then use them. It appears that to do this from GAS is difficult, as you will have to implement the oauth flow itself. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount.